# Vuejs 2.0 v-model conflitando com v-bind:value em elementos diferentes

Tags: vue.js-2

Tenho um formulário com alguns inputs que tem v-model e outros com v-bind:value recebendo um valor inicial pelo 'data'. Toda vez que digito algo em um campo com v-model ele reseta o valor dos campos com v-bind:value para o valor inicial.

O erro acontece apenas na versão 2.x do vuejs.

jsfiddle com um exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/ypeacuth/

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    nome: 'Ted',
    sobrenome: ''
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" v-model="nome">
  <input type="text" id="sobrenome" name="sobrenome" :value="sobrenome">
</div>
```

Comment: A explicação do @rnd_rss está correta... Quando você faz `<input :value="sobrenome">` você está dizendo que a propriedade `value` vai ser sempre o que estiver dentro de `data.sobrenome`.. E como `data.sobrenome` é uma _string_ vazia e nunca é modificado, o comportamento do Vue é tornar o `value` uma _string_ vazia sempre que renderizar o componente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse é mesmo o comportamento das diretivas, lembre que só o `v-model` tem **two way data binding**, ou seja se você alterar o input ou o valor que está no seu data o vue mantém eles 'sincronizados'. Já com o `:value` isso não acontece se você alterar o valor do input não vai alterar o valor no data pois ele tem **one way data binding**, nesse caso a reatividade acontece somente do data para o input. Então se entendi direito o que você precisa vai ser necessário alterar o `:value` para `v-model`.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    nome: 'Ted',
    sobrenome: ''
  }
})
```

---

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" v-model="nome">
  <input type="text" id="sobrenome" name="sobrenome" v-model="sobrenome">
</div>
```

Fontes: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Value-Bindings

Comment: Você pode usar o :value para setar um valor inicial, porém por ele não vai ser possível atualizar o sobrenome(a variável que esta no data), se preencher alguma coisa no input do sobrenome o :value não atualiza o valor do input no sobrenome, é sempre e somente o sobrenome(que está no data) atualiza o input. Mas se você vai precisar setar um valor inicial e depois esse valor pode ser atualizado o jeito é mesmo usar o v-model